# Knockout –> Wijmo Grid: Is it possible to have the Columns as an observable?

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, grid, wijmo

I am using the Wijmo Grid with Knockout and I would like to first create an empty grid with no columns to it and change dynamically the columns of the grid and it options.

That is, actually completely update de columns during runtime.

Also, from the examples, just some of the Wijmo Grid options can be observables.

I would like to know if Columns can be an observable too and which Grid options can/cannot be.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the Columns option of Wijgrid cannot be bound to an observable object in KO. The only options that can be bound to KO are the ‘data’ and ‘disabled’ options (http://wijmo.com/docs/wijmo/#KOGridBinding.html).

You may post this feature as an enhancement request on our UserVoice Page
(http://wijmo.uservoice.com/) so that other users can also vote and it can implemented on priority.